# Why $I(\varphi )=\int_0^T \dot \varphi ^2$ has compact level sets in $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$ the space of continuous function $f:[0,T]\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $f(0)=0$ endowed with the supremum norm. Let $$H_1=\{f:[0,T]\to \mathbb R\mid f\text{ absolutely continuous and derivative in $L^2(0,T)$}\}.$$

Set $$I(\varphi )=\begin{cases}\int_0^T\dot \varphi ^2&\varphi \in H_1\\ +\infty &\varphi \notin H_1\end{cases}.$$

Can someone explain how to prove that $I$ has compact level sets ? i.e. why $$L_\alpha :=\{\varphi \in \mathcal C_0[0,T]\mid I(\varphi )\leq \alpha \},$$
is compact ? I tried to prove that is sequentially compact : Let $(\varphi _n)\subset L_\alpha $. So $I(\varphi _n)\leq \alpha $ for all $n$. In particular, $\varphi _n\in H_1$. But how can I prove that there is a convergent subsequence ?

Answer (score 0):

The existence of  a convergent subsequence follows easily from Arzela-Ascoli Theorem. we have $|\phi (t)-\phi (s)|=|\int_t^{s} \dot {\phi} (x)dx| \leq \sqrt{\alpha} \sqrt {|t-s|} $. This gives equicontinuity and we get uniform boundedness by putting $t=0$. Hence $L_{\alpha}$ is relatively compact in $C_0[0,T]$.

$L_{\alpha}$ is  not a closed subset of $C_0[0,T]$ and hence it is not compact.

Comment: What do you mean by equicontinuity ? Sorry I'm novice in functional analysis. How do you conclude relatively compactness ?

Comment: @user659895 Whenever you want to prove that a sequence  in this space has  convergent subsequence w.r.t. sup norm yo should immediately think of Arzela-Ascoi Theorem. This basic theorem can be found in many books and you can also do a net search. Equi-continuity is defined in these books. Proving the existence of a uniformy convergent subsequence without this theorem is possible but somewhat tedious. You have to find subsequence which converge at each rational and then use  a diagonal argument.

Comment: Ok, I saw on wikipedia. But why relatively compactness of $L_\alpha $ implies $L_\alpha $ compact ?

Comment: ok, and since it's a metric space, it's obviously compact, right ? (because sequentially compact implies compact).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the point. I agree that $|\phi(t)-\phi(s)|\leq \sqrt \alpha \sqrt{|t-s|}$. This only thing I can say is $\{\varphi (t)\mid \varphi \in L^\alpha \}$ is relatively compact for all $t$ (i.e. the closure is compact). In what this prove that $L_\alpha $ is compact ? Why do you take $t=0$ in your proof ?

Comment: Arzela- Ascoli theorem also requires uniform boundedness of the sequence. I am putting $t=0$ to get boundedness. But I think compactness of $L_{\alpha}$ is not true art all. We can only  say it is relatively compact (which means its closure is compact).

Comment: $L_α$ is a subspace of $C_0$ and convergence in $L_α$ translates, by similar arugments as you used, to uniform convergence in $C_0$. Thus $L_α$ is closed in $C_0$, and the result should be compactness.

Comment: @LutzL uniform convergence does not preserve the condition $\int \dot {\phi}^{2} \leq \alpha$.

Comment: This was not claimed. The claim was the other way around, that convergence in the $H^1$ norm implies uniform convergence, thus that convergence in $H^1$ implies convergence in $C_0$.

Comment: The statement of OP is very ambiguous. In what norm is $L_{\alpha}$ supposed to be compact? I don't see a clear mention of this. I am thinking of this as a subset of $C_0[0,1]$ with the sup norm.  @LutzL